# Continuous numbering of questions in exam class

Tags: enumitem, exam

How to get the same feature as `resume` in the `enumitem` package for the `questions`env in the exam Latex class?

For instance,

```
\begin{questions}
  \question A?
  \question B?
\end{questions}
Some text.
\begin{questions}
  \question C?
\end{questions}
```

should give something like

```
Question 1. A?
Question 2. B?
Some text.
Question 3. C?
```

Comment: An easy way to handle your situation is to use `\fullwidth{Some text.}` in the `exam` class. You do not have to leave the question environment to use it.

Answer (score 7):

You can literally do want you want by saving and restoring the question counter.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question A?
  \question B?
  \xdef\mycounter{\arabic{question}}% macro
\end{questions}
Some text.
\begin{questions}
  \setcounter{question}{\mycounter}%
  \question C?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

---

But exam class already provides you with `\uplevel` and `\fullwidth` to manipulate the indentation.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question A?
  \question B?

\fullwidth{Some text.}

  \question C?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First part works through sections. Great !

Answer (score 1):

I use the exam class for various exercises. The exercises include questions interspersed lengthy passages of text. I outdent the question numbers to help questions standout from the text. My answer does not directly address your question (a resume-like feature) but I wanted to point out that you do not have to leave the question environment to use fullwidth text.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % For this example.
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{-\leftskip}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is some introductory text.

\begin{questions}

\question[5]
Here is a question.

\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

Here is some text. \kant[1]

\question[5]
Here is another question.   

\vspace*{3\baselineskip}

Here is some more text. \kant[2]

\end{questions}

Final summary text.

\end{document}
```

[image]